# MemoryError in "to_sql" command in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I am working on a jupyter notebooks on AWS Sage Maker. I have performed text processing on a data with 5000 rows. I want to write this to another SQL query with the following code.

```
conn=sqlite3.connect('final_2.sqlite')
c=conn.cursor()
conn.text_factory=str
final.to_sql('Reviews',conn,schema=None,if_exists='replace')
```

Its saving a 2.09 GB and its stopping. When I open this is file its not considering as file. Then I tried to write to a .csv file but still same issue.
When I downloaded and opened the csv I am getting the following error.

```
Jupyter Notebook
current mode
File
Edit
View
Language
1
Error! Traceback (most recent call last):
2
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1699, in _execute
3
    result = await result
4
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
5
    yielded = next(result)
6
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/handlers.py", line 112, in get
7
    path=path, type=type, format=format, content=content,
8
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 438, in get
9
    model = self._file_model(path, content=content, format=format)
10
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 365, in _file_model
11
    content, format = self._read_file(os_path, format)
12
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/fileio.py", line 309, in _read_file
13
    bcontent = f.read()
14
MemoryError
15
​
16
Saving disabled.
17
See Console for more details.
```

I tried checking my free space in python and there is still about 30 GB free space.

Can someone please let me know what is the issue with this situation.Thank you !

Comment: maybe it means problem with RAM memory, not disk space.

Comment: Check out my solution. It is likely to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

This exact problem happened to me. I have resolved the problem by increasing the RAM size.

The problem occurs becuase `to_sql` command is trying to convert the entire dataframe to SQL code. At one point it runs out of memory.

A work around it to load the data in batch like this:

```
batch_size = 10000
for i in range(0,range(len(final)),batch_size):
    final[i,i+batch_size].to_sql('Reviews',con=conn,schema=None,if_exists='append')
```